# Can't ping external IP addresses in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, networking, ping

I have **two** devices connected to my network. I've made a simple Android application to detect connected devices using ping.

[image]

The application runs in the device with the IP **192.168.1.14**.

The code below is used to **ping** IP addresses (**I've tried all available methods**, I get the same results ):

```
    String ipAddress = "192.168.1.";
    for (int i=1; i < 255; i++){
        String ip = ipAddress + i;
        InetAddress inet = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
        if (inet.isReachable(300)){
            Log.d(TAG, ip + " is reachable.");
        }
    }
```

I've got the following results:

> 192.168.1.1 is reachable.
>
> 192.168.1.14 is reachable.

But I didn't get **192.168.1.15**

Comment: Maybe 192.168.1.15 does not answer pings. Look at your firewall settings.

Comment: No, I've tried the code above from different devices it works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428675/list-devices-on-local-network-with-ping?rq=1